# Intellij IDEA plugin for YouTrack

Tags: intellij-idea, issue-tracking, youtrack

I got interested in YouTrack and thought I should give it a go since apparently it has good integration with IDEA. I've setup the tasks server in IDEA, but what now? How can I view the list of all tasks, start/stop work on them, etc.? (I was previously using JIRA with it's connector plugin in IDEA so I'm trying to do the same with YouTrack)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to [read the related documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-integration-with-an-issue-tracking-system.html) [sections](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/managing-tasks-and-context.html). If you have more specific questions, please edit your original question.

Comment: I've read the documentation, but that's all? This comes nowhere near the JIRA plugin.

Comment: Yes, that's all at the moment. If you have feature requests, welcome to http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA.

Comment: “Unfortunately the page you are looking for is currently unavailable or does not exist on our web-site.”

Answer (score 1):

YouTrack can only be integrated as a provider of tasks. It is not like Atlassians IDE-Connector which allows you to eork completely in the IDE with issues.

Also note that when you connect YouTrack as a task provider, by default you will only see open tasks assigned to you. So you need to first go to the YouTrack web and assign an issue to you, then it will show up in IDEA.

Unlike using JIRA as task provider it will not provide you with a list of tasks, you have to search by complete task id for it to show up.